Simple scss map generated by for loop
I want to have a map like this:
$spacers: (
   0: 0,
   1: 4px,
   2: 8px,
   etc.
);

This is my code:
$spacer: 4px;

$spacers: ();

@function map-set($map, $key, $value) {
  $new: ($key: $value);
  @return map-merge($map, $new);
}

@for $i from -5 through 12 {
  map-set($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
}


Yet I'm thrown an error

I tried different variations, adding the loop inside a function, etc., but I get the same error...

You have to set the values of $spacers to the return value of map-set. I am also assuming map-merge is another function you wrote, otherwise just use the built in map.merge method and add @use "sass:map" to the top of your file.
$spacer: 4px;
$spacers: ();

@function map-set($map, $key, $value) {
  $new: ($key: $value);
  @return map-merge($map, $new);
}

@for $i from -5 through 12 {
  $spacers: map-set($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
}

You could also just write the following (although I do not know your use case so please ignore if this isn't useful):
@use "sass:map";

$spacer: 4px;
$spacers: ();

@for $i from -5 through 12 {
  $spacers: map.set($spacers, $i, $i * $spacer);
}

